# namp a target why using sS options take longer time than sT

Tags: networking, tcp

It is strange that when i nmap -sS Target,I take longer timer than when I namp -sT Target.(both I have root).In the namp docs, the namp sS option send a syn packet should take less time than sT option which tend to complete a TCP connection with target.

It there any reason for this?I use nmap 6.40 on Ubuntu14.04.